# How to append text to Div form jQuery in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, checkbox

How to add `CheckBox` Name to `Div control` when Check box `Checked` status true through Jquery

I've tried the below code. but not get the result.

ASP CODE:

```
<div align="center" id="chkBoxes">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chbIceCream" Text ="Ice Cream" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chbCake" Text ="Cake" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chbChocolet" Text ="Cho colet" runat="server" />
</div>

<div id="ContentDiv">


</div>
```

Jquery CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chbIceCream').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var Text = $('#chbIceCream').text();
        if ($(this).attr('checked'))
            $('#ContentDiv').append(Text);
    });
});
```

If any one help in that please .

Answer (score 3):

Set your control [ClientIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) if you want to use server side id in javascript or use CliendID in javascript.

**Using ClientIDMode="static"**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chbIceCream" Text ="Ice Cream" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

*No change in jQuery selector for control id*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chbIceCream').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var Text = $('#chbIceCream').text();
        if ($(this).attr('checked'))
            $('#ContentDiv').append(Text);
    });
});
```

**Using ClientID**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%= chbIceCream.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var Text = $('#chbIceCream').text();
    if ($(this).attr('checked'))

        $('#ContentDiv').append(Text);
   })
});
```

Comment: i am using script for seperate js file @Adil

Comment: it populates this error @Adil 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= chbIceCream.ClientID %>'

Comment: Yes it should give error I have updated my answer you need to use first option of ClientIDMode="static"

Comment: still i got same Error @Adil

Comment: With ClientIDMode you do not need  #<%= chbIceCream.ClientID %>'

Comment: Sorry..! @Adil I have tried this combination also but i didn't get the solution

Comment: I could not understand why it does not work, put just single alert in your script and build your website and try again and tell me what error it gives you.

Comment: Actually it doesn't shown any error after line by line compilation i found that  it will returns empty string to `Text` @ADil

Comment: you need to use text() instead of append() change to $('#ContentDiv').text(Text);

Comment: Sorry..! the problem is not in  `$('#ContentDiv').append(Text)` it will accept other strings. but `$('#chbIceCream').text()`; returns empty string ......

Comment: @Adil at last i got solution i have found solution  `$("input:checkbox[id$=chbIceCream]").next().text()`;

Comment: Thats great, but I would say try using $(this).next.text()

Answer (score 0):

use this as selector

```
 $('#<%= chbIceCream.ClientID %>').click(function(){
  ....
```

**UPDATED**

add `ClientIDMode="static"` in your html

Comment: it populates this error @bipen 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= chbIceCream.ClientID %>'